# git log origin/master..HEAD but include origin/master itself

Tags: git, git-log

This is my full git log.

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate

77cbdda (HEAD -> master) file4
8afab80 file3
9a4cd72 file2
76c2efc (origin/master) file1
```

I want to get log from origin/master to HEAD.
When I tried

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate origin/master..HEAD
```

I got log msg like below

```
77cbdda (HEAD -> master) file4
8afab80 file3
9a4cd72 file2
```

But what I want is like below.

```
77cbdda (HEAD -> master) file4
8afab80 file3
9a4cd72 file2
76c2efc (origin/master) file1
```

How can I get log message like that?

Comment: I guess `76c2efc (origin/master)` is your very first commit. So, when trying `origin/master~1`, it does not exist in your working tree

Answer (score 2):

use ~1

`git log --oneline --decorate origin/master~1..HEAD`

Comment: I have tried that one already. But I got error msg like below ---> fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master~1..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree....

Comment: Will it work as OP want if `origin/master` is merge commit?

Answer (score 1):

`origin/master..HEAD` means what exists in *HEAD* that is not in *origin/master*.

`9a4cd72 (origin/master) file2` exists both *HEAD* and *origin/master* so, it is not in the list

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate origin/master~1..HEAD
```

This should work unless `76c2efc (origin/master)` is your very first commit. So, when trying `origin/master~1`, you are getting error cause it does not exist in your working tree actually.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the reason why I got error when I command

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate origin/master~1..HEAD
```

That's because origin/master was the **first commit**. If it was second commit or more, there is no error.

Thank Edmundo.

Comment: Right: the problem is that `~1` means "move one further back" and there's no way to go any further back.  Fortunately, since the whole point of `stop..start` is to exclude `stop`-and-earlier, once you know there's nothing earlier, you can just use `start` here.

Comment: @torek How about `git start --not stop^@`?

Comment: @PetSerAl: interesting; that should work for the general case (though you would normally spell it `^stop^@`, `--not` persists until another `--not`—kind of a subtle point...). It's better than `--boundary` since `--boundary` can include *too many* commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git log --oneline --decorate HEAD --not origin/master^@
```

The `origin/master^@` will select all parents of `origin/master` commit whenever it one, zero or many. And `--not` will exclude this commits (and its parents) from listing.

Note: you need to exclude all the parents commits, because if you exclude only mainline parent `origin/master~1`, then commits from all merged branches will got listed in case `origin/master` is merge commit.